# Could not read file Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a custom controller for this [application](https://sourceforge.net/p/kablink/code/HEAD/tree/). you can find a sample under /ssf/samples/customcontroller. For my customcontroller I use the Spring-Frameworkwhich is also used by the kablink project. Now I try to execute a sql script (my.sql) via `getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query, String.class, new MapSqlParameterSource());`. The sql file contains only one line `select label from question where questionid=3;`

But I run into  difficulties by reading the file my.sql. In the Controller I call the method `graph.sunburstJson()` and push the return value to the view:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/resources/spring/config/GraphBean.xml");
        GraphDao graph = (GraphDao) context.getBean("graphDao");
response.setRenderParameter("json", graph.sunburstJson());
```

To see if the method sunburstJson reads the file I try to return the content of my.sql:

```
public class GraphDaoImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements GraphDao{

    @Override
    public String sunburstJson() {
        String query="select label from question where questionid=5";

        try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/spring/sql/my.sql");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            LineNumberReader fileReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
            query = JdbcTestUtils.readScript(fileReader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            query=errors.toString()+"help";
        }
        return query+"test";//(String)getSimpleJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query, String.class, new MapSqlParameterSource());

    }
}
```

But it returns no error and no output, I cant explain what happened. This starts with the line `JdbcTestUtils.readScript`. The same behavior with

```
EncodedResource resource = new EncodedResource(context.getResource("/resources/spring/sql/my.sql"), "UTF-8");
```

If I try

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/spring/sql/my.sql")));
 //or
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/resources/spring/sql/my.sql"));
```

I get a file not found exception stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide some more information and more of the code so that we can help you.

Comment: Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

I add a new version of the [library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadspringtest321RELEASEjar.htm) to the project now it works properly.